# View (2) Joined Tables?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a view with two joined tables, but I can't seem to get it working. Here's what I tried:

```
Create View OwnerBe As
-> Select CID
-> From OwnTable a, BeTable b
-> Where a.CID=b.CID;
```

ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'CID' in field list is ambiguous

Thanks. :)

Comment: You need to alias the column -- `select a.cid` -- also I would recommend using `join` instead of `where`...

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should stop using the ancient, outdated and error-prone implicit joins in the `where` clause and start using an explicit `JOIN` operator

Answer (score 0):

```
Create View OwnerBe As
Select a.CID
From OwnTable a, BeTable b
Where a.CID=b.CID;
```